# Filebeat index is getting created but with 0 documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am trying to index my custom log file using filebeat. I am successfully running filebeat with pre-built modules like mysql, nginx etc. But when I actually try to use it with my application specific log file, index is created with 0 documents.

I could not find anywhere in the filebeats document if there are any specific steps need to be taken to ensure indexing takes place for the custom log files.

I did not get any error when I setup filebeats or run filebeats post setup.

Below is the filebeat.yml:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/247around-adminp-aws/application/logs/log-2020-12-21.log
  include_lines: ['^INFO', '^ERROR']
  fields:
    app_id: crm
filebeat.config.modules:
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
setup.kibana:
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
processors:
```

As can be seen, it is majorly default .yml file with very minor changes.

My custom log file log-2020-12-21.php is:

```
INFO  - 2020-12-21 15:10:26 --> index Logging details have been captured for employee. Details are : Array
INFO  - 2020-12-21 15:10:36 --> editpartner partner_id:1
INFO  - 2020-12-21 15:10:36 --> SELECT DISTINCT service_id, brand, active
ERROR - 2020-12-21 15:10:36 --> Query error: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'boloaaka.collateral.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
INFO  - 2020-12-21 15:10:36 -->  Database Error: A Database Error Occurred<br/>Array
ERROR - 2020-12-21 15:10:54 --> Query error: Expression #5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'boloaaka.service_centres.district' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
INFO  - 2020-12-21 15:10:54 -->  Database Error: A Database Error Occurred<br/>Array
INFO  - 2020-12-21 23:53:21 --> Loginindex
INFO  - 2020-12-21 23:54:50 --> Loginindex
INFO  - 2020-12-21 23:55:42 --> Loginindex
INFO  - 2020-12-21 23:56:24 --> Loginindex
```

Index file is getting created with 0 documents:
[image: Filebeats index with 0 document]

Log file showing logs for filebeats setup and filebeats running:
https://pastebin.com/TK6uYXuq

Please help:

1. Why there are no error messages if something is wrong because of which documents are not getting indexed? I should be getting some error if things are not right.
2. How should I index my log file?
3. Where should I add pattern for my log file like key-value pair which would help me in searching the documents for relevant values later on?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your filebeat configuration, are you sure you are referring to the exact file where your logs are stored? Your 'paths' in filebeat.yml is referring to a .log file extension while the custom log file you've pasted is `log-2020-12-21.php` Try changing your paths to match this .php extension instead.
If filebeat correctly picks this file up, you could see something like the code below in your filebeat logs

```
INFO log/harvester.go:287 Harvester started for file: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/247around-adminp-aws/application/logs/log-2020-12-21.php
```